# How to simplify hash intersection with array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have hash data (originally in json) and an array of selected hash keys:

```
jsondata ='{"1":
          {"name": "Tax Exempt"},
       "2":
          {"name": "Tax on Purchases"},
       "3":
          {"name": "Tax on Sales"},
       "4":
          {"name": "Service Tax"}              
        }'
parseddata = JSON.parse(jsondata);    
selectedtax = ["2","3"]
```

My code maps the keys and returns the value of the hash that exist in the array. Here is the code:

```
selectedtaxdetails = Array.new
parseddata.map do |key,value|  
  if selectedtax.include? key 
    selectedtaxdetails << value               
  end
end
```

Output of `selectedtaxdetails` is:

```
[{"name": "Tax on Purchases"},{"name": "Tax on Sales"}]
```

How can I improve my code?

Comment: you should use some underscores: `selected_tax_details` is easier to read

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: Is json parsing relevant at all to your question? If not, remove it. Give the hash in Ruby. Give only the relevant parts.

Comment: whats wrong with you sawa ? which part of the code is not working! i just ran this in ruby with of course require 'json' and it works.

Comment: @Axil No it doesn't. What is wrong with you? Think by yourself.

Comment: totally non-constructive

Comment: @Axil - You missed an opening quote here: `selectedtax = ["2",3"]`

Comment: sorry bout that, updated, it works anyway the code above just unoptimized. thanks #BroiSatse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution:

You can do (rails):

```
parseddata.slice(*selectedtax).values
```

or even simpler (pure ruby):

```
parseddata.values_at(*selectedtax)
```

### Explanation:

Both `slice` and `values_at` methods expect a list of keys. If you just pass an array it will search for values where this array is a key, whcih obviously is not what you want. Instead you can use a splat operator (`*`). It will take each element of an array and will pass it into a method as a separate argument, which is exactely what we want here.

### Update:

To achieve structure: `[{"code":"2", "name": "Tax on Purchase"},{"code":"3", "name": "Tax on Sales"}]` you can do (rails):

```
parseddata.slice(*selectedtax).map {|key, value| value.dup.tap {|h| h['code'] = key}}
```

or with pure ruby:

```
parseddata.select{|key,_| selectedtax.include? key}.map {|key, value| value.dup.tap {|h| h['code'] = key}}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained the use of the splat operator.

Comment: +1 for [`values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

Comment: @MikeCampbell - here it is. :)

Comment: thanks! works perfectly. got another question, if i wanted to return {"code":"2", "name": "Tax on Purchase"},{"code":"3", "name": "Tax on Sales"}. how do i construct a new structure for the returned array ?

Comment: @Axil - Sorry, I just noticed that method under update will mutate original hash. Will fix in a second.

Comment: ok, i cant get the slice working though. `<main>': undefined method `slice' for #<Hash:0x00000101111230> (NoMethodError). im just running this on command line. do i require something ?

Comment: @Axil - This is rails (ActiveSupport core extension) method, I'll update with non-rails code in a second. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the same in one line

```
parseddaata.values_at(*selectedtax)
```